# « Pas de problème » ou « pas de problèmes » ?

Tags: grammaire, orthographe

Chaque fois que je veux employer la formule « Pas de problème(*s*). », je coince.

Comment faut-il l’écrire ?

> Pas de problèmes.
>   Pas de problème.

Naturellement, j’ai envie d’employer la première formulation, mais puisqu’il est possible d’avoir un problème sans en avoir plusieurs, je ne sais pas si elle est grammaticalement correct.

En général, je me résigne à écrire « aucun problème » pour éviter le problème. Mes recherches dans le Grevisse se sont révélées infructueuses<sup>1</sup>.

Alors, les deux formulations ci-dessous sont-elles correctes ? Sinon, laquelle l’est ?

---

1. Mais je cherche très mal dans le Grevisse.

Answer (score 6):

S'il n'y a *pas de problème*, c'est qu'il n'y a *aucun problème* à résoudre, même pas un. La situation actuelle n'est pas un problème en soi.

S'il n'y a *pas de problèmes*, c'est que les problèmes qui se présentent ne sont pas des vrais problèmes, qu'ils sont déjà résolus ; aucunes des situations présentes ne pose de problème parmi les nombreux problèmes possible.

> Pas de problème pour résoudre cette équation.
>
> Pas de problèmes en vue pour réaliser ces nombreux petits travaux.

La pure logique voudrait que *pas de problème* soit la réponse idéale, car s'il n'y a aucun problème, il ne peut y en avoir deux.

La situation vécue dénombre les problèmes possibles et leur nie toute réalité.

Il semble que l'usage courant soit indifférent, d'autant plus qu'à l'oral il n'y a pas de distinction.

Peut-être que pour l'écrit l'Académie française a donné des règles, mais je les ignore.

Comment: Un dessin humoristique illustre la réponse : http://www.langue-fr.net/spip.php?article220&debut_articles_rubrique=10#pagination_articles_rubrique

Comment: J'ai toujours pensé que la règle était binaire à l'écrit i.e. s'il n'y en a pas, même pas un, alors comment pourrait-il y avoir accord en nombre? Mais à 512c, Grevisse vient encore décoiffer, indiquant que si la forme positive de la phrase eût pris le pluriel, alors aussi la négation: _Le navire roulait sous un ciel sans nuageS._ (Baudel). Je vois aussi au [Trésor](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pas) Balzac: _Pas de zèle, pas d'histoires, pas un mot._ Merci pour le lien, je vais lire sur la _syllepse_!

Answer (score 0):

Je n'ai jamais vu la formule *« Pas de problème ! »* écrite autrement qu'au singulier. 
De même qu'en anglais *“No problem!”*, en italien *Non c'è problema !* et en espagnol *No hay problema !*